# problem with name domain resolution (I believe)

Tags: raspbian, networking, dns

The problem is I can ping for example google's ip address but not the domain name (browsing to google.com works as well)
`sudo apt-get update` gives the following :

```
0% [Connecting to mirrordirector.raspbian.org (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3)] [Co
```

Comment: `Co` ... wonder what it says after that

Comment: Nothing .... it stops there

Comment: what is the result of running `cat /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: it was 
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 2607:fa48:6e80:2690:c256:27ff:fe71:80ab

Comment: changed it to 8.8.8.8 for the first one and 8.8.4.4 for the second didn't solve the issue

Comment: does `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update` work?

Comment: @tobyd https://pastebin.com/urUTaMu9 improved a little bit but still hungs after that

Comment: What's your network setting? Do you use wired or wireless connections, `/etc/network/interfaces`, dhcpcd, `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, or what?

Answer (score 0):

This happened quite often lately with Raspbian Stretch, somehow running `apt-get update` screw up the gateway setting. This can be observed by run the following command:

```
route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

Run this command to add the gateway:

```
route add default gw [Gateway_IP] [Iface]
```

in my case, it is

```
route add default gw 192.168.0.1 eth0

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Nope, this wasn't the case here my routing was like the second one